# Product set in a finite field

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, additive-combinatorics

For a finite nonempty subset $A$ of a ring $X=(X,+,\cdot)$, let us denote the set $\{a \cdot b \colon a, b \in X\}$.

If $X=\mathbb{Z}$, it is not difficult to show that

$$|AA| \leq \frac{|A|^{2}+|A|}{2}.$$

Do you know of a similar bound for $|AA|$ when $X$ is a finite field (say, of prime order)?

Comment: It looks unlikely; the nonzero elements of a finite field form a cyclic group. When $|A|$ is a lot smaller than $|F|$ then the situation looks like $(\Bbb Z,+)$ and a similar bound looks best possible. When $|A|\sim\sqrt{|F|}$ then surely one can get $AA=F$.

Comment: So, in general, we can't but say $|AA| \leq |A|^{2}$?

Comment: Seems that at least for fields of prime order that's true. Just treat $A\subset\mathbb{F}_p$ as a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I don't get it, why the same proof for $\mathbb{Z}$ doesn't work for the finite case. We still have the commutative property and so the map $f:A\times A \rightarrow AA$ given by $f(a,b)=ab$ is 2 to 1 on the subset $a\neq b$, so the size of $AA$ is at most $(n^2-n)/2+n=(n^2+n)/2$ where $n=|A|$.

Comment: Is it 2 to 1? Seems like for every unit $g$ in $A$, $f$ sends $(ag,bg^{-1})$ to $ab$.

Comment: At least 2 to 1, if it is say 10 to 1, then we get even a better bound.

Comment: I see. Cool!...